# Why is $\frac{n}{n+1}\bar{X}^{2}$ an unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}$.

Tags: statistics

**Question:** Let $X_{1} \cdots X_{n}$ be a sample from the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, where $\lambda > 0$ is an unknown parameter. Why is $\frac{n}{n+1}\bar{X}^{2}$ an unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}$.

To my understanding a unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}$ needs to be an $A$ such that the following holds:

$$\mathbb{E}[A] = \frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}$$

since, $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ and $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}^{2}] = \frac{2}{\lambda^{2}}$

Then I get $\mathbb{E}[\frac{n}{n+1}\bar{X}^{2}] = \frac{n}{n+1}\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}^{2}]$
$=\frac{n}{n+1} \frac{2}{\lambda^{2}} \neq \frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}  $

Comment: Why do you say $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}^{2}] = \frac{2}{\lambda^{2}}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{n}{n+1}\overline{X}^2\right] &= \frac{n}{n+1}\mathbb{E}\left[\overline{X}^2\right] = \left[
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbb{V}[\overline{X}] = \mathbb{E}[\overline{X}^2]-\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}]^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}^2] = \mathbb{V}[\overline{X}] +\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}]^2
\end{array}
\right] = \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\left[\mathbb{V}[\overline{X}] +\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}]^2\right] = \left[
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbb{V}[\overline{X}] = \frac{1}{n\lambda^2} \\
\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}]^2 = \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}
\end{array}
\right] = \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n\lambda^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right) = 
\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{n+1}{nλ^2} = \frac{1}{λ^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$